# cannot float img and div inside a div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to left `float` an image and a `div` inside another `div`

```
<div class='cardL'>
<img class='imgL' src='init/left.jpg' alt='image'>
<div class='txt'>
<p>aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
<div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cardL{
    border:2px ridge #b30000;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.imgL{
    float:left;
}
.txt{
    float:left;
    background:yellow;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

`img` and `div` are not floated, but stacked.

jsfiddle is [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tXjD7/)

(what else should I write ? I see a red note here that the post is not detailed enough, and cannot send it. So all of this text is without needing)

Comment: img and div which get floated need a width to know if there is space to float: http://jsfiddle.net/tXjD7/1/

Comment: Provide widths to your elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a `width` to `float`.

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/tXjD7/2/

Answer (score 2):

Do `display: block;` to your floating elements and a width.

Comment: `display: block;`? You don't need that when you `float`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the style from:

```
.imgL{        
    float:left;
}
```

to:

```
.imgL{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```